# python threading method stuck

Tags: python, multithreading, daemon, python-multithreading, raft

I have a class `MyClass` which creates 7 threads when it is initialized. One thread is a TCPServer, and the other six are objects of `MyClass` which the TCPServer uses to process requests.

My intention is to create method which can run in the background of `MyClass` and maintain the 6 threads. The 6 threads correspond to 2 distributed objects `obj1` and `obj2` replicated with an implementation of Raft called PySyncObj. There are three threads per object.

Each cluster of objects `obj_1_cluster` and `obj_2_cluster` has a leader, which the server must keep track of, because all changes to the object must be sent only to the leader.

```
class MyClass(object):

def __init__(self):

    self.server = TCPServer()

    self.obj_1_cluster = self.init_cluster(Class_1['bindings'], Class_1)
    self.server.obj1 = self.get_leader(obj_1_cluster)

    self.obj_2_cluster = self.init_cluster(obj_2['bindings'], Class_2)
    self.server.obj2 = self.get_leader(obj_2_cluster)


    # Create Daemon process for keeping leader current.
    self.obj1_leader_daemon = Thread(target = self.__obj1_leader_daemon())
    self.obj1_leader_daemon.setDaemon(True)
    self.obj1_leader_daemon.start()

    self.obj2_leader_deamon = Thread(target = self.__obj2_leader_daemon())
    self.obj2_leader_deamon.setDaemon(True)
    self.obj2_leader_deamon.start()

def __obj1_leader_daemon(self):
    while True:
        print("Running obj1 daemon")
        if self.server.obj1._isLeader():
            pass
        else:
            self.server.obj1 = self.get_leader(self.obj1)

def __obj2_leader_daemon(self):
    while True:
        print("running obj2 daemon")
        if self.server.obj2._isLeader():
            pass
        else:
            self.server.obj2 = self.get_leader(self.obj2)
```

When I run this code, the only output I see is...

```
Running obj1 daemon
Running obj1 daemon
Running obj1 daemon
...
```

until I kill the process with ctrl-C.

Is there a way to change this so that these two processes can run with their own thread- busily checking the state of the objects in case they need to change them? I've read a lot about threading and I don't see why this isn't currently working the way I think it should.

Environment: I'm running python 2.7.14 on MacOS 10.13.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__` gets stuck at

```
self.obj1_leader_daemon = Thread(target = self.__obj1_leader_daemon())
```

The thread target should be the name of the function to run, but you've called the function instead. `self.__obj1_leader_daemon()` is an infinite loop so it never returns, nothing is assigned to `target` and no thread is ever created. Your main thread hangs running the daemon code.

Just remove the cowboy legs

```
self.obj1_leader_daemon = Thread(target = self.__obj1_leader_daemon)
```

... and do the same for the other thread.

Comment: Thanks! This was painfully obvious. This works just fine now